# Run Eclipse in verbose mode

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, accurev

Is there any way to run Eclipse CDT in verbose mode?
When I want to open a project it takes forever to finish (the activity scroll bar keeps scrolling with no end). I am hoping to get some insight into the issue by looking at the logs that may be generated in verbose mode.

is there any log file in Eclipse that may help figuring out these kind of problems?

EDIT: one more data point is I recently started to use Accurev version control and since then I experience these kind of issues with Eclipse.

Comment: Does this happen just after you open a workspace or long after  workspace is opened and the resulting workspace rebuild has completed?

Comment: It happens right after I open a workspace.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely that there's a lot of CPU being chewed up by the workspace being rebuilt and other startup activities (maven re-indexing, workspace re-indexing, other tools trying to run faster later by making you wait longer now).  Try limiting the number of open projects in the workspace by closing projects not in use or by factoring set of inter-related projects into separate workspaces.

I don't think you can have any impact on the time it takes to initialize the tools on workspace open, unless you can reduce or disable any tools you don't need or you reduce the number of projects those tools act against.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also suggest making sure you are using the latest plugin for Eclipse for AccuRev, if you believe it is part of the problem. You can also contact AccuRev support as they may have additional tools for investigating problems like this.